# setuptools entry_points. Installing executable to /usr/sbin

Tags: python, setuptools, packaging, entry-point

I have a setup.py script, that has entry_points defined like this:

```
entry_points = {
    'console_scripts': [
                        'gun = gun.sync:main'
                       ]
                },
```

This installs the executable into /usr/bin. Is there any way I can tell entry_points to install it to /usr/sbin instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  You have to pass the `--script-dir` option to easy_install to specify that.

(You *could* add it to your project's setup.cfg file, but it's not recommended because it'll surprise people who have configured their Python installation to install scripts to some other location...  and even if you do it, it'll only take effect for users who actually run your setup.py.  Most other installation tools will ignore a script path specified in a project's setup.cfg.)